# Safely allow upload of web fonts (ttf, eot, svg, woff, otf) via MIME TYPES / fil

Tags: php, linux, mime-types

I'm trying to allow safe upload of web fonts in our application, by checking against mime types. This works for most types of files we allow, but it's a problem for web fonts.

We check the mime-type by using PHP's http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php

The problem is that php will detect all web fonts as mime "application/octet-stream", but allowing that, would allow .exe or many other possibly dangerous file uploads.

What is the best way to handle upload of this kind of files?

Answer (score 1):

Find a magic file that contains info about the font formats, and pass that to `finfo_open()`.

Comment: found the file in /usr/share/, how can I update this file with font formats?

Comment: Grab it from the latest [file](ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/). You'll need to run `configure` and then go into `magic/` and run `make` there in order to generate the file.

Comment: the problem is that we're running CentOS and don't want to go around yum

Comment: You don't need to. Just put your magic file somewhere else and refer to it explicitly.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll try that. Is there a version file that says from which version web fonts are supported in the file commands magic.mime file?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You'll have to inspect the various files within `magic/` to be certain.

Comment: is there a way to get the most recent magic.mime file without having to configure/make/... ?

Comment: If you can find a prebuilt version somewhere then you can extract it from that archive. Note that you don't have to built it *on that system*; the magic file is architecture- and OS-independent.

Comment: When running make in the magic directory it just says "Makefile is up to date". Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Hrm. You may have to build it from the base directory then.

Comment: Ok I ran make from the base dir, but after that, searching for magic.mime did not return any results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't rely on mime checkers built in the PHP. I always have problems with them. If your running linux, use the PHP's exec command to execute mimetype command in bash and return it to PHP.

Comment: that would be an option but then we'd have to open up exec in PHP, which is blocked right now for security purposes

Answer (score 0):

U should use [phpinfo](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to check extension, mime type can be fake, and U can get .php file with mime type of a pdf.

EDIT

```
$file = "abc.ttf";

if(in_array(strtolower(pathinfo(file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("ttf")))
{
    // OK
}
```

u can add more extensions to array

Comment: how would you reliably detect a TTF file that way, do you have a sample or link on how to accomplish that?

Comment: I have add an example to my anwser

Comment: thanks, but that gives me "exe" if I rename a file abc.ttf to abc.exe

Comment: Yes but its the safest way to do this.

Comment: How can it be the safest way if users can simply rename files and upload anything to the server. At least MIME types check for actual contents of the file, making it more secure than only checking file extensions?

Comment: Becouse mime type can be fake, as I wrote it before u can upload .php file with mime type of ttf. Read about seting mime types to files

Comment: sure, but when only checking extensions, you can simply rename a .php file to .ttf and have it upload whatever you want? Is that safer than checking mime types?

Comment: Yes its safer becouse if U change file name from .php to .ttf apache will not parse this file and eaven if there is danger code it will not be executed

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Can someone confirm that or explain how Apache can safely serve any kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

If TTF files are the only ones allowed to be uploaded, use this:
http://www.phpkode.com/scripts/item/ttf-info-plus/

Comment: there's also OTF, SVG and other web fonts that should be uploaded. As a matter of fact, we'd like to be able to allow just any kind of files in the future, as long as we can verify it's content at least based on MIME types