# Can imagettfbbox use URL's?

Tags: php, php-gd

The PHP manual page for `imagettfbbox` says:

> *fontfile*
>   The name of the TrueType font file (can be a URL)

but passing a URL gives a `Unable to access` error.

I have a number of fonts on my Amazon S3 account, like 
 http://bililite.s3.amazonaws.com/webservices/fonts/Lilly.ttf
and I'd like to use them on a webpage, with

```
$box = imagettfbbox (12, 0,
  'http://bililite.s3.amazonaws.com/webservices/fonts/Lilly.ttf', 'Hello, World');
```

But I just get the error. I've tried it on two different servers with two different providers, and other URL's besides S3 and get the same error. The URL is valid; I can download the font. `allow_url_fopen` is set.
Is the manual wrong about using URL's? If I'm stuck, I can curl the font URL into a temporary file and use that, but I'd rather not.

Comment: At first, try to use a local font.

Comment: Local fonts work fine. Grabbing the font file with `file_get_contents` and saving it to a temporary file, then `unlink`ing it when I'm done works fine. I'm trying to avoid storing huge files on my website, especially multiple ones.

Comment: Do you think a font file is huge?

Comment: Perhaps because the font at this address is delivered with the HTTP header application/octet-stream?

Comment: @yunzen:I'm using nearlyfreespeech.net and they base all their charges on storage; it's much cheaper to put big files on S3. Also, the appropriate MIME-type for ttf fonts is application/octet-stream ([http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128069/ttf-mime-type]). Do you know of a better one?