# @font-face not working in FireFox, possible caching issue?

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I thought I had my head around this... Had it working many times before. This works fine in Chrome:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'idealsans_book';
    src: url('http://staceyclarke.com.s3.amazonaws.com/idealsans_book.eot'); /* IE fix */
    src: url('http://staceyclarke.com.s3.amazonaws.com/idealsans_book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* another IE fix */
         url('http://staceyclarke.com.s3.amazonaws.com/idealsans_book.wof') format('woff'),
         url('http://staceyclarke.com.s3.amazonaws.com/idealsans_book.ttf') format('truetype');
    src: local('idealsans_book'),
        url('fonts/idealsans_book.woff') format('woff');
}
```

But doesn't work in FF... I am using [Paul Irish's Bulletproof @font-face Syntax](https://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/).

Please help.

Comment: Use something like [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) to generate your CSS, then alter as needed. I've had issues with random behavior when it comes to using font-face, and I've found that they way they do it, it almost always works.

Comment: switching to their code helped for sure :) -- amazon wasn't serving my fonts with the correct mime type! (also)

Comment: Amazon AWS was not serving font files with the correct [MIME type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871655/proper-mime-type-for-fonts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a look in Chrome and FF (all updated) and it looks like the font is working correctly for the most part. Take a look (chrome in background, FF on top)

[image: Font Face]

Perhaps it's caching on your end. I did noticed some odd characters in FF though (see lower right hand corner, red circle). Could be charset.

Also, take a look at this blog post I wrote about [font-face in CSS3](http://maxfelker.tumblr.com/post/5673285606/cross-browser-solution-to-css3-font-face).

Additionally, perhaps Google code help you out with their new [font api](http://www.google.com/webfonts).

Comment: Yes, I do think it was the caching in the end... Thank you for that! I also discovered the hard way that amazon does not serve fonts with the correct MIME type!