# How do I get fonts to download on web when the exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, webfonts

For some reason my glyphicons are not displaying.  When I look at the files in the inspector, they show up red, because they are byte 0.  However I can access the links successfully:

http://admin.packagezen.com/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

[image: Font files exist but they come in with 0 bytes]

Any idea, what is happening?  Is it heroku perhaps? or rails?  I put the fonts in /public/assets and the file exists when i ssh into the server.

Comment: Do you need to configure rails to serve up `.woff` files as mime type `application/x-font-woff` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644391/rails-3-web-font-woff-mime-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the rails assets pipeline to serve this for your. Do the following:

Drop that font in (not in public/assets):

```
/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

Add the font face in your application.css that uses this font/url, this will reference the finger-printed version of this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons';
  src: font-url("/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Then feel free to use that name anywhere to reference that font. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add to the config/application.rb file the following (within class Application < Rails::Application)?

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/fonts"
```

E.g. source: http://www.erikminkel.com/2013/09/01/twitter-bootstrap-3-in-a-rails-4-application/