# Mime types for svg on a apache web server

Tags: apache, webserver, mime-types

I have .svg fonts and .svg images on a website.

I have a problem with the mime types on the server.

When i set this mime type:
font/opentype svg

Than the .svg images are disappeared. What do i am wrong?

What mime types should i set on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The mime type should be: `image/svg+xml`

Comment: Do you have a live page I can hit? That is the correct mime type for svg. I'm using it myself. For the fonts, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871655/proper-mime-type-for-fonts