# @font-face not working with IE running on XP

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts, font-face, webfonts

Problem sample: http://www.osdev.org/squirrel/card.html

Problem sample2: http://www.osdev.org/squirrel/dejavusans-demo.html

I'm looking to use symbols from the Unicode 6 U+1F0A0–1F0FF range (Playind Card Block) http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F0A0.pdf but even ascii ranged characters aren't rendered in the font and whatever font is being used on IE/XP doesn't have symbols for the playing card block.

Version 2.33 of DejaVu Sans added playing cards, the ttf font is available at http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page.

- I've tried every EOT generator I can find. The second sample is the demo page generated by http://www.fontsquirrel.com.
- I've tried making IE only pages just in case the CSS font url wasn't being picked up correctly.
- I've used FontForge on the original ttf to make all the family, unique names, etc match before running the font through eot generators.

If I install the ttf locally (in the Windows XP fonts folder) I can use css font-family without font-face to display the font in IE but I can't ask everyone to do that.

IE8 on Windows 7 seems to work but IE6, IE7, and IE8 on Windows XP all fail. It is like font-face just doesn't do anything on XP.

Any suggestions? I asked on the http://www.fontsquirrel.com forums first but haven't received any responses.

Edit: To clarify, IE on XP renders the playing cards as an empty square, the same "blank" symbol that is used when your system can't display any character.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of your server settings. I'm using Chrome on a Mac, so I cannot actually "see" your problem.

But I looked the content-type in your font file's Response-Headers. It's `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`. I think this is your problem.

You should change the settings of your server to make the response have the correct `Content-Type`. Or IE may think that the file is not a valid font file.

Try Google "font file content type" for more information.

And I think this will help you too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864297/1061004

Comment: Thanks but the eot format was already returning application/vnd.ms-fontobject as the Content-Type. I did go ahead and add the types for woff and ttf but that did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Include two fonts, first is for IE and rest is for all other browsers.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "SocialFoundicons";
  src: url("//www.tintup.com/public/css/foundation_icons_social/social_foundicons.eot");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "SocialFoundicons";
  src: url("//www.tintup.com/public/css/foundation_icons_social/social_foundicons.eot"),
   url("//www.tintup.com/public/css/foundation_icons_social/social_foundicons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
   url("//www.tintup.com/public/css/foundation_icons_social/social_foundicons.woff") format("woff"), 
   url("//www.tintup.com/public/css/foundation_icons_social/social_foundicons.ttf") format("truetype"), 
   url("//www.tintup.com/public/css/foundation_icons_social/social_foundicons.svg#SocialFoundicons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```