# SECURITY_DENIED_BY_MIMEMAP error when serving WOFF font from Azure

Tags: azure, mime-types, woff

I've got a test Wordpress site running in Azure as an Azure Website using the Wordpress install from the Azure gallery.

The site is functional and appears to be working as expected. With one exception. I'm using a custom webfont - http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/.

This font has an OTF, SVG, TTF, EOT and WOFF version. From what I understand different devices/browsers use different versions of the file to render to the font.

I'm having a problem serving the .woff version of the file.

I have turning on the logging within the Azure portal and I can see the following error

> SECURITY_DENIED_BY_MIMEMAP
>
> FileName
>   C:\DWASFILES\SITES\WWW-MYWPTESTSITE\VIRTUALDIRECTORY0\SITE\WWWROOT\WP-CONTENT\THEMES\AVADA\AVADA\FONTS\FONTAWESOME-WEBFONT.WOFF

I have confirmed that the .woff file exists on the server by logging into via SFTP and browsing to the folder.

I have seen other posts online about adding this information to the web.config file. Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
            <staticContent>
              <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
              <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
              <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
            </staticContent>
        </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, I'm not sure how this can, or should, be added to the Azure hosted site.

UPDATE: Save the above code as web.config and upload to the wwwroot folder. Azure will now allow the .woff font to be downloaded when requested.

Answer (score 7):

Save the following as web.config. Upload the web.config file to the wwwroot folder of the site hosted in Azure. The .woff files will now be served.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
            <staticContent>
              <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
              <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
              <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
            </staticContent>
        </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is the  `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>` line an unrelated setting? I just added the `staticContent` element and its children, and it worked for me.

Comment: There are better [mime-types available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20723357/712526)