# Firefox webfont not working on one of two domains

Tags: firefox, webfonts

I implemented a webfont on our website. The website is available through two domains:

http://blog.von-der-see.de / http://www.vds-blog.de

The webfont is implemented this way:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Quattrocento-Sans;
    src: url('./style/Quattrocento Sans.woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Quattrocento-Sans-Bold;
    src: url('./style/Quattrocento Sans Bold.woff');
}
```

If you view the website in firefox through both domains, you will see that the font is not working on one of two domains.

The website is a wordpress and if i switch the home-url to the other domain, its not working on the on, but then on the other domain.

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding font mime types in your htaccess?
Just out of interest why are you only using woff? No true type etc?

Comment: I googled but didnt find out how to add font mime types in htaccess.

I dont really know why we only use woff. Its given by other developers here...

Comment: No, unfortunately not :(

Comment: I'd download a font from here http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ and use their code. You can use this site to also generate the other file types. To set mime types see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871655/proper-mime-type-for-fonts just add these lines to a file called .htaccess and add to the root of your server. These files are hidden in OS X so you'll need to show invisible files. HTH

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vds-blog.de/ doesn't load webfonts.

By changing style.css url in theme's header page
from

`<link href="http://blog.von-der-see.de/wp-content/themes/vondersee/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`
 to 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.vds-blog.de//wp-content/themes/vondersee/style.css">`

may solve your problem.

Comment: Do that change for http://www.vds-blog.de/ only! I mean to say, for http://www.vds-blog.de/ site, link should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.vds-blog.de//wp-content/themes/vondersee/style.css">` and for http://blog.von-der-see.de site, link should be `<link href="http://blog.von-der-see.de/wp-content/themes/vondersee/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Its one website. Both domains link to the same server

Comment: If you can, change `src: url('./style/Quattrocento Sans.woff');` to `src: url('http://blog.von-der-see.de/wp-content/themes/vondersee/style/Quattrocento Sans.woff');` and same for `src: url('./style/Quattrocento Sans Bold.woff');` to  `src: url('http://blog.von-der-see.de/wp-content/themes/vondersee/style/Quattrocento Sans Bold.woff');`

Comment: Did you revert it?? because I see `@font-face {
font-family: Quattrocento-Sans;
src: url('./style/Quattrocento Sans.woff');
}`   `@font-face {
font-family: Quattrocento-Sans-Bold;
src: url('./style/Quattrocento Sans Bold.woff');
} `