# Icon fonts not loading in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, webfonts

We're using icomoon for our icon fonts, and they work fine in Chrome and Firefox, but won't display in IE11... Sometimes.  It seems to work on the first page load, but not on subsequent page loads.  Clearing the cache doesn't seem to reset it.  This issue may be present in other IE versions, right now we're just focusing on IE11.

Here's our @font-face:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icon';
src:url('fonts/icon.eot?-3q3vo5');
src:url('fonts/icon.eot?#iefix-3q3vo5') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icon.woff?-3q3vo5') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icon.ttf?-3q3vo5') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/icon.svg?-3q3vo5#rezku') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
font-family: 'icon';
speak: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;

/* Better Font Rendering =========== */
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.icon-alphabet:before {
content: "\e600";
}
/* etc etc etc */
```

But here's where it gets weird.  Looking at the developer tools, an HTTP request for the fonts is being sent, but only a few hundred bytes are being received (probably just the headers).

[image: Network panel]

But the HTTP response lists the content length correctly as several kilobytes.

[image: Response headers]

The "Response body" tab just says "No data to view."

You can see in the Network Panel screenshot that the Google Fonts aren't behaving like this.

Pasting the URL in the location bar results in the full file being downloaded.

Comment: Check your mimetypes, and ensure the font names/filenames/font-face names are all alike (IIRC, IE has an issue with generic names). Also, are they served from the same domain as your site? (no subdomain?)

Comment: They are served from the same domain.  The font names/etc do match up.  It looks like TTF is being reported as "application/octet-stream", I'll fix that and report back.  The other MIME types seem to be fine.

Comment: I pointed IE to the dev environment on my Mac, and the fonts seem to work consistently.  I have no idea what the difference would be, the code is exactly the same as the live server.

Comment: Is this still up to date or did you find a fix in the meantime?

Comment: No fix yet.  We ended up dropping IE support.

Comment: IE has a problem finding the .eot file if the family name is different from the embedded font name (not file name).

Personally i wouldn't bother about it, MS Edge will be released in a month or 2 with win10, because it's a free upgrade everyone should be on it.

Comment: @Matthew Rath What do you mean by the embedded font name?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ran into a similar problem, and from your screenshot above, the response has a Cache-Control header of 'no-store'. IE seems to have issues with caching and fonts.

Removing both the 'Cache-Control: no-store' and the "Pragma: no-cache" headers worked for us to get icon fonts to show up again.

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/6454

Answer (score 15):

After investigating the very same issue, and going through various solutions posted online, I've created the following troubleshooting list, which covers most potential causes:

1. Font downloads are disabled in IE, under Internet Options / Security / Custom Level / Font Downloads enable /disable. They might be disabled by your network admin, in which case you would not be able to see nor change this setting.
2. Your HTTP headers prevent IE from storing the font file locally. To fix, remove any `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache` or `Pragma: no-cache` headers, or any `Expires` header with a date in the past. Also the `Vary` header has its tricks in IE, if set to anything other than `Accept-Encoding`, `User-Agent`, `Host` or `Accept-Language` then IE will not cache anything, **unless** an `ETAG` header is also present (see [this MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9/)).
3. You don't set the correct MIME types for the font download. For example Jetty 9 will set by default `Content-Type: text/plain` for the usual font types (`eot, woff, woff2`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864297/981913) for the proper content types to use.
4. Make sure to use `display: block` or `display: inline-block` for your icon element.
5. Finally, make sure to go through the [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting) over at FontAwesome.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problem but with Bootstrap font icons (Glyphicons). You can try if this works:

(Generally on Windows 10) the IE-11 settings have been changed to not download any external fonts and use only the fonts available in windows. This is the default behavior.

However we can change this setting in IE to enable it to download external fonts. Following are the steps to be taken in IE-
Go to: Settings >>  Internet Options >> Security
[image]

Click on “Internet” (or any zone that you may be using) >> “Custom level…”
Next in the ‘security settings’ – Enable ‘Font Download’. By default it would be disabled.
[image]

Refresh the Page

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and it seems to be caused by IE having difficulty with certain `display` and `position` settings in combination with iconfonts.

It should usually work using:

```
element:before {
     display:block;
     position: absolute;
     ... your styles ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is correct, however there may be an issue with the way whatever converter you used to converted from .tff to .eof. See this the article for more details on this matter in general http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2009/12/webdev/adventures-with-font-face

In the mean time you could try testing the problem by using a font hosted by Google fonts. I say this because Google handles cross browser compatibility seamlessly. If it turns out that the Google font works then you know its a problem with the way that your font was converted and you need to try another one. From what I understand [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) is really good at generating cross browser compatible fonts. I hope this helps good luck

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/block-untrusted-fonts-in-enterprise#Turn_on_and_use_the_Blocking_untrusted_fonts_feature

Basically Microsoft is making us have to go back to using sprite sheets.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was corrupted .eot font file.  I had generated new one ( + new .css styles) and it fixed the problem. Try it.

PS. Make sure you support EOT for IE at @font-face, for example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "fontName";
  src:url("../../src/theme/fonts/fontName.eot");
  src:url("../../src/theme/fonts/fontName.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
  url("../../src/theme/fonts/fontName.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../../src/theme/fonts/fontName.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("../../src/theme/fonts/fontName.svg#fontName") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```