# IE and Font Awesome

Tags: internet-explorer, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome icons on my website which display fine in Chrome, Firefox, Edge etc but don't show in any version of IE, not even the square boxes.
I obviously thought I had an issue with my site until I went over to the Font Awesome website using IE and noticed no icons displaying there either. 
The F12 console displayed this error message
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.

[Chrome, Firefox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5C3I.png)

[IE screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFELd.png)

I'm deducing from this that there has to be a local setting in IE which I need to adjust, screenshot was taking with compatibility view off.
Any views appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Disablement of downloadable fonts has probably been implemented.  DISA STIG DTBI030-IE11.

[Try this solution that uses base 64 and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44528995/7470581) to force the fonts through.

This is fixable.  You just need to *Base64* the font and include it in a CSS file. Make sure to remove your call to the downloadable WOFF file once you include the call to the new FontAwesomeB64.css

Use https://www.base64encode.org/ to encode the WOFF Font-Awesome font file.

Edit the the resulting file and add these lines.  When you get to the src:url line, make sure to run that right into the base64 information you received (don't use the greater than and less than signs I show here.)  At the end of that base64 information add the single quote, parentheses, a semi-colon, and curly brace to finish:

```
@font-face { 
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src:url(data:application/x-font-woff;base64,<insert base64 code here>);}
```

You now have a base64 CSS file of the Font-Awesome font that bypasses all font download denial settings in browsers.

I've found that this works with all fonts, a little heavier on the download but worth the guarantee of functionality.

Comment: please include content to your answer

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely related to [IE 11: error CSS3111 in my own code, and google.com/fonts doesn't render any fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023461/ie-11-error-css3111-in-my-own-code-and-google-com-fonts-doesnt-render-any-fon/34048445?noredirect=1#comment55883898_34048445)