# Why are my icons not showing up in IE and only show up when I log into my account?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, http-headers, font-awesome, eot

I'm having an issue with my icons loading in Internet Explorer.  At first I thought it was a **https** but my whole website is in **https**.

When I go to my homepage in IE, **all my icons are missing** and I notice in the network session the following:

- icons.eot? 200 OK application/vnd.ms.fontobject
- icons.woff?-ot1xzl 200 OK application/octet-stream
- icons.tff?-ot1xzl 200 OK font/tff

However, when I log into my account I then notice **all the icons showing again** and in the network session I only see this being shown:

- icons.eot? 200 OK application/vnd.ms.fontobject

I'm not sure why by logging into my account all my icons start showing again and only the above is shown instead of all 3 when I'm not logged in.  **Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?  Maybe it's a session issue?**

The following is what I have saved in my CSS file:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('../fonts/pb-icons.eot?-ot1xzl');
    src:url('../fonts/pb-icons.eot?#iefix-ot1xzl') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/pb-icons.woff?-ot1xzl') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/pb-icons.ttf?-ot1xzl') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/pb-icons.svg?-ot1xzl#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What account are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, by I "account" I meant where my customers would log into their account on the front-end of my website.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by removing "Pragma: no-cache" and "Cache-Control: no-store" like it mentions in the link below.

[Icon fonts not loading in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894319/icon-fonts-not-loading-in-ie11?rq=1)