# Serving google fonts with webfont loader not working on ie11

Tags: internet-explorer, google-webfonts, webfont-loader

I am trying to load a font from Google Fonts using WebFontLoader.

It works perfectly on all browsers but IE 11 + Microsoft Edge.

**The problem:** the first time the font is loaded, it is not shown. 
In this page there are two iFrames. On first loading, the first iFrame is not loaded, but the second is
[loading fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORemi.png)

But when I hit refresh, both iFrames 
[load correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7iRK.png)

This has made me think it has something to do with caching - the file it not loaded the first time.

From what I read here : 
[Icon fonts not loading in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894319/icon-fonts-not-loading-in-ie11)
and other places I understand this is an issue with IE not loading files with no-cache flag.

Various answers on the web claim that this is solved with removing the 'no-cache' flag from the server or setting "Cache-Control "max-age=3600"" flag.

**The problem is I am not serving the files myself**, they are loaded dynamically using WebFont-Loader directly from Google Fonts, and i cannot change these flags.

I am unable to host them myself because product considerations, I can only serve files from Google Fonts (also to enjoy the benefits of caching for other browsers).

Comment: We seem to be having the same problem. Did you stumble upon a solution?

Comment: FYI - it appears that it was the number of fonts (one call per font), but now google allows you to do one request for many fonts, so changing this fixed it.