# XSL- How to put meta tag as the FIRST tag in the head on XSL

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xslt

Currently, my XSL Generate html page with some meta tag, css and JS link file in `<head>` tag. I have added one more after search over Stackoverflow site for Internet Explorer compatibility issue to support Font Awesome icon on compatibility view.

But my XSL generate html as follows-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-16" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css>
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

XSL Source:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
    <xsl:include href="portalheader.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="case">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
                <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Some stack member suggest me to put the meta tag as first tag of head to support Font Awesome icon on IE compatibility view.
Ref. Stack Answer  - [font awesome not working in ie9 & ie11 compatibility mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853420/font-awesome-not-working-in-ie9-ie11-compatibility-mode/39853484)

Current scenario not working with IE compatibility view.

My Questions -

1. How to put the 'X-UA-Compatible' meta tag as first?
2. Is it working for IE compatibility view (IE9 & IE11) ? or if you have any other solution please share.

Regards,

Comment: It does not seem like the given source produces the given result.  For one, the meta tags do not match.

Comment: I missed the viewport tag - consider as output

Comment: so how to put 'X-UA-Compatible' tag in first position?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `method="xml"` instead of `method="html"`?

Comment: I need HTML output @ Daniel

Comment: Since you're using an `http-equiv`, why not removing it from HTML and serve it as a HTTP header?

Comment: I try to remove it, but it's automatically generate by XSL Stylesheet@Xeons