# In the IE browser, icon fonts not showing

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts, icons, basic-authentication

In the environment with basic authentication, icon fonts not showing.
Icon fonts are displayed in other browsers or environments without basic authentication. Also, after authentication, if access each page directly from the URL or browser reloading, the icon is not displayed, but if page transition from link click, the icon is displayed.

There is a difference in the response between direct access to the page and access by link click, so describe. Access by link click contains eot, woff, ttf font files in the response, but direct access contains only eot file.(I do not know if there is a relationship...)
Also, the next board confirmed.
[Icon fonts not loading in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894319/icon-fonts-not-loading-in-ie11)
However, the browser response header doesn't contain cache control.

Here's my @font-face:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal
}
```

Do you have any other information you need to solve? Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IE security settings set to high as the security level, web fonts are not downloaded by default.

I suggest that you could try to modify the group policy of font downloads in IE.

Follow the steps:

- Open Local Group Policy Editor
- Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer -> Internet Control Panel -> Security Page -> Internet Zone
- Select Allow font downloads -> Enable -> Apply

[image]